# android dictionary application with offline database

Tags: android, sqlite, database

I want to develop an android English dictionary application that uses only an offline database. By that, I mean to say that it doesn't have to be redirected to online dictionary like WordWeb or the like. Does anybody know what should I do to store my words? I'm thinking of using SQLite since it's mobile. But if anyone here already has done or did something what I want to do, can you give me some expert suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/src/com/example/android/searchabledict/DictionaryDatabase.html

I have used this code from  developer.android.com .
Hope it will help you also.

EDIT: This page is no longer available, but the example itself is on Github [here.](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SearchableDictionary)

Comment: this sample is not available. Is there any chance that you have a copy of it. appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry @Chann Never feared that this could be removed from the repository.

Comment: found it in git. thanks for the reply https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SearchableDictionary

Comment: is there a newer version its 4 to 6 years ago update

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with using SQLite, that's probably the easiest and most straightforward way to do it on Android. Of course the complexity of this solution depends on you exact needs. If you only need a really simple dictionary, then you could get away with a simple db schema with basic queries.

Another thing that comes to mind is the Trie data structure, you may want to look into that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Dictionary_representation . But it probably wouldn't worth the hassle to pull this off using this, I'd guess that the performance of the SQLite solution is more than enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I already did this to my dictionaries:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=e-Biene%20DEV&hl=en

You can make conversion to your simple database, 
tblLanguage1[word, translation]
tblLanguage2[word, translation]

to (SQLite format [extract it from emulator], and then attach this converted SQLite db with your App offline).

It will be quick and fast for searching.

and Use:  DB created in emulator with structure like:
Tables:

lang1_Content
lang1_segments
lang1_segdir

use this instead of simple.

Comment: Please link to the Source Code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Google API samples, I know they have a Dictionary application. I'm pretty sure it's offline too. I had to build something with an offline cache, I used JAVA's excellent XML parser to load things into the SQLite database. When the user had an internet connection, it would download a new XML and use that to update the database. You can store any type of file with your application however.

http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html
The sample I'm talking about is called Searchable Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is to specify what essential will store your dictionary.

There are a lot of ways provided by Android to store your data such like:

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

File saved in device's [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) or [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

[SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

You also may create a static database and store it in your `assets` folder as described in [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) post.

Also you may check for Searchable Dictionary from `android-samples` which is a good example of implementing a search for your app and also there described some technics of storing data.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is that - keep your data in files say in json file and keep it on the web or you can also uplaod this on googledrive or dropbox and make it public and after that when user will open the app for first time, download the json files and insert the data from json into sql lite db.This way you can use sql lite for offline data.